# smcure package error

Tags: r, regression, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I would like to perform a cure analysis, and when I run the code below:

```
pd <- smcure(Surv(FAILTIME,FAILCENS)~trt+Age1 , cureform =~trt+Age1 ,data=saba, model="ph",nboot=1000)
```

This error is reported:

> Error in rep(1, n) : invalid 'times' argument

Answer (score 0):

This error is most likely due to an NA in your dataset.